# Can't get IEnumerable type using linq filtered query

Tags: linq, ienumerable, where-clause

i have been finding problems related to the following code..Actually i want to select filtered records but it gives me 0 records. I have tried the following. Please Help me..

```
public static IEnumerable<PostModel> GetPostData(string cat)
{
var data = new LinqClassDataContext();                                                   IEnumerable<PostModel> pm;
pm=data.PostTables.Where(Post => new PostModel
{ CategoryName= Post.CategoryName}.Equals(cat)).Select
(Post => new PostModel 
{     PostID = (int)Post.PostID, 
      PostSubject = Post.PostSubject,
      PostAuthor = Post.PostAuthor, 
      PostDate = Post.PostDate, 
      PostContent = Post.PostContent, 
      CategoryName = Post.CategoryName
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your `PostModel` class object would be Equals string cat?
Maybe you meant:

```
data.PostTables.Where(Post => Post.CategoryName == cat)
```

Even though you overrided Equals method on `PostModel` I think you should use line I meantioned above because it is more obvious.

Also at the end of query you should call `.ToList()` method for initiating it. And you should dispose context after creating it in the method.

```
public static IEnumerable<PostModel> GetPostData(string cat)
{
   var data = new LinqClassDataContext();                                                   
   var pm = data.PostTables.Where(post => post.CategoryName == cat)
                         .Select(Post => new PostModel 
                                {     
                                   PostID = (int)Post.PostID, 
                                   PostSubject = Post.PostSubject,
                                   PostAuthor = Post.PostAuthor, 
                                   PostDate = Post.PostDate, 
                                   PostContent = Post.PostContent, 
                                   CategoryName = Post.CategoryName
                                })
                         .ToList();
   data.Dispose();
   return pm;
}
```